# React-modal not working properly with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im trying to use the react-model component but bootstrap is messing it. When i put it outside the div with col class it works fine but separaiting it messes up the layout. Here the component in which i use the modal.

```
class BeerItem extends Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    showModal: false,
  };
}

handleOpenModal = () => {
  this.setState({ showModal: true });
}

render(){
  Modal.setAppElement('#root');
  return (
    <div key={this.props.beer.id} className="col-sm-8 col-md-4 m-3 beer-item col-xl-3 text-center" onClick={this.handleOpenModal}>
      <div className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center hvr-rotate">
          <div className="img-container">
            <img src={this.props.beer.image_url} alt=""/>
          </div>
        <div className="beer-nametag">
          <p className="h5 font-weight-bold beer-card-name">{this.props.beer.name}</p>
          <p className="text-secondary">{this.props.beer.tagline}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Modal 
        className="modal"
        isOpen={this.state.showModal}
        onRequestClose={ () => this.setState({ showModal: false }) }
        shouldCloseOnOverlayClick={true}
        ariaHideApp={false}
      >
        {this.props.beer.name}
    </Modal>
    </div>
  )
}
}
```

This is an item component which is rendered in a list component. I tried to put the modal in the list component but then i cant figure how to pass the beer id into it. The list is in a infinity scroll component and when i want to update the state in the list by passing a function to item component which takes the id of clicked beer i get an error with maximum depth exceed...

Answer (score 0):

- You can use `<React.Fragment>`, so the you doesn't wrap the components with an extra `<div>`.
- Many modal render outside the view window when it's closed (For animation purpose). However, you might want to completely remove it from the DOM after close event.

The tested code. Notice, the `Modal` is rendered conditionally based on `this.state.showModal`:

```
const MyModal = props => (
  <Modal
    className="modal"
    isOpen
    onRequestClose={props.onClose}
    shouldCloseOnOverlayClick
    ariaHideApp={false}
  >
    {props.beer.name}
  </Modal>
);

class BeerItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showModal: false,
    };
  }

  handleOpenModal = () => {
    this.setState({ showModal: true });
  };

  onModalClose = () => {
    this.setState({ showModal: false });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div onClick={this.handleOpenModal}>Click me</div>
        {this.state.showModal && <MyModal onClose={this.onModalClose} beer={{name: "Beer"}} />}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I just put it in React.Fragment and it solved the problem with any extra effort. I just want to know if its good to put the modal i every item-component of an list-component or should i have it in one place and just pass data to it?

Comment: @titans It's not. Topically, you don't inject a modal in the middle of a grid (`table`, `ul`, etc.), since that's incorrect use of html element. It's  normally by having a modal outside grid, and then display it when callback event handler is triggered (bubble up).

Comment: So i should put it on the top of everything? Im using bootstrap so im assume that it should be over the top container?

Comment: @titans Place the modal anywhere outside list/table. For example: `<tr><td key="1">cell1</td><div>{/*Modal*/}</div><td key="2">cell2</td></tr>`, this kind DOM will get you in trouble.

Comment: When i said "list" i meant a react list component which holds item components. I didnt mean an html list.

Comment: @titans JSX syntax is a list React components which are reacted from `React.createElement()` they are no different to the stateless components you normally write. You have to look into the generated HTML file to identify if it's valid or not.